# Как грамотно сделать выпадающий список на Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Задача: нужен выпадающий список, элементы которого будут иметь 3 возможных состояния. При клике  на какой-нибудь элемент, остальные сбрасываются в дефолтное состояние, а этот переходит в следующее. Если это последнее состояние, то опять на дефолтное и так далее.

Проблема: Не понимаю где хранить состояние этих объектов, если у меня есть директива `dropdown` и в ней есть директивы `dropdown-item`. Хранить ли в общем или в каждом. Хочу увидеть хорошее объяснение, грамотное с точки зрения кода (Если возможно, то без $parent и т.п.). И еще проблема как грамотно связать состояние и визуальную часть чтобы не загрязнять верстку чем-то типа `ng-class="{ state == 0 : first_state, state == 1 : second_state, state == 2 : third_state }"`

Вот мой "код", его надо переписать, но мне сложно понять как лучше это сделать

```
.directive('dropdown', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
      $scope.dropdown = {
        'states' : {
          'cost' : 0,
          'dist' : 0,
          'area' : 0,
          'sqr'  : 0
        }
      }
    },
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
      $scope.dropdownOpened = false;

      $scope.handleDropdown = function () {
        $scope.dropdownOpened = !$scope.dropdownOpened;
      }

      $scope.clearAll = function () {
        for (var st in $scope.dropdown.states) {
          if ($scope.dropdown.states.hasOwnProperty[st]) {
            $scope.dropdown.states[st] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
})

.directive('dropdownItem', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  var state;

  return {
    scope: false,
    link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
      $scope.state = $scope.$parent.dropdown.states[attrs.type];
      state = $scope.state;

      elem.bind('click', function() {
        $scope.$parent.clearAll();
        $scope.state = state;
        $scope.nextState();
      });

      $scope.nextState = function () {
        if (state == 0) {
          state = 1;
          $scope.state = 1;
        }
        else if (state == 1) {
          state = 2;
          $scope.state = 2;
        }
        else if (state == 2) {
          state = 0;
          $scope.state = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  };
}])


<dropdown class="dropdown__dropdown___3u4Vf utils__btnWideXs___1hFlV" placeholder="Сортировать">
          <div class="dropdown__placeholder___32H9C" ng-click="handleDropdown()" ng-class="{dropdown__active___2Yw9D : dropdownOpened}"><span class="dropdown__activePlaceholder___391kS">Сортировать</span><span></span>
            <svg class="dropdown__icon___2sXCw dropdown__iconBig___Dv0Ea" icon="arrow-down">
              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#arrow-down"></use>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown__container___62pzX dropdown__active___2Yw9D" ng-if="dropdownOpened == true" ng-cloak>
            <dropdown-item type="cost" ng-class="{ state_0 : state == 0, state_1 : state == 1, state_2 : state == 2 }" class="button__btn button__md button__block button__btnInner___3h7VL">по цене</dropdown-item>
            <dropdown-item type="dist" ng-class="{ state_0 : state == 0, state_1 : state == 1, state_2 : state == 2 }" class="button__btn button__md button__block button__btnInner___3h7VL">по удаленности</dropdown-item>
            <dropdown-item type="area" ng-class="{ state_0 : state == 0, state_1 : state == 1, state_2 : state == 2 }" class="button__btn button__md button__block button__btnInner___3h7VL">по пл. участка</dropdown-item>
            <dropdown-item type="sqr" ng-class="{ state_0 : state == 0, state_1 : state == 1, state_2 : state == 2 }" class="button__btn button__md button__block button__btnInner___3h7VL">по пл. дома</dropdown-item>
          </div>
        </dropdown>
```

Comment: часть с объектом можно заменить на массив: `[first_state, second_state,third_state ][state]`. Стоит добавить пример того, что уже есть

Comment: @grundy Там я делал и остановился, т.к. вообще не работает. Мне бы саму суть понять, какой алгоритм действий

Comment: алгоритм же у тебя уже есть: _При клике на какой-нибудь элемент, остальные сбрасываются в дефолтное состояние, а этот переходит в следующее. Если это последнее состояние, то опять на дефолтное и так далее._

Comment: @grundy Мне нужен более подробный алгоритм. Стоит ли юзать 2 типа директив родители и его дочерние директивы. Ну а лучше фидл с минимальным функционалом. Я не совсем понимаю как правильно работать со скопами. Вот лично я сделал что-то вроде `$scope.dropdown= { 'states' : { 'cost' : false, 'distance' : false, 'area' : false } }` в родительской директиве, а потом делал `<dropdown-item type='cost'></dropdown-item>` ну и так далее что показывать стыдно. Я понимаю что это не правильно и не реюзабельно

Comment: Показывать что есть, нужно хотя бы за тем, чтобы знать в каком направлении ты двигался. Иначе можно просто посоветовать использовать готовый dropdown, например из bootstrap

Comment: @grundy Ну вот я дополнил, но нужны кастомные элементы, а не готовые. Функционал будет расти со временем